# Bug: FAQ navigation bar links scroll to wrong place

Tags: bug, faq-for-site

On the [FAQ page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq), there is a navigation bar on the right, showing all the different sections of the FAQ, for quick navigation.

In that list, the following two links scroll the user to the wrong content section of the FAQ:

- What about subjective questions
- Where can I ask subjective, discussion, and other questions not fit for this site?

All the other navigation bar links seem to work correctly, and take the user to the correct content section.

Can those two links be fixed, please?

Comment: Probably related to the same underlying issue:  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-can-i-not-link-directly-to-faq-anchors

Comment: So its by design then? :P